# Metro Search Charm - clear search box programmatically after user accepted the result suggestion

Tags: c#, search, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I would like to clear the search box in metro search charm after the user accepted one of the result suggestion my app is providing to the charm. How? Sounds easy but it is not, SearchPane.QueryText is read only.

I am actually surprised by the default system behavior. After the user accepted the ResultSuggestion (please remember to distinguish from QuerySuggestion) it does not make sense in my eyes to pre-populate the search box with this accepted result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user's text stays there in case after looking at one of the results they decide "oh that's not it, I will look at this other result from" and the other result could even be from a different app.  There is no way for an app to override this.

Comment: Hi Robert, many thanks for your answer. I understand your words however in all honesty this does not make much sense to me. Actually it does - for SUGGESTIONS. But for RESULTS??? Search box is a place where user enters a QUERY to find some RESULT(s). She just spent her time by looking at the 5 results why should she do it again in the box? Now, after placing the RESULT into the search box this RESULT becomes a QUERY. Yes, I can imagine situations where the same or another app can use this but I need a lot of imagination - the probability is low. Anyway, I am afraid I will have to accept this..

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var searchPane = Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.SearchPane.getForCurrentView();
searchPane.trySetQueryText("myQueryText");
```